# MS Access: Transposing a database table horizaontially

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database table with 3 columns and 10K rows similar to below:

```
IMPORT_ID   EXPORT_ID TIMES_REPEATED
SI1313721   SI1440839    2
SI1313721   SI1440997    2
SI1313722   SI1440672    3
SI1313722   SI1440776    3
SI1313722   SI1441313    3
...
```

IMPORT_IDs are getting repeated (SI1313721 - 2 times, SI1313722 - 3 times). I want to transpose this table into

```
SI1313721   SI1440839   SI1440997
SI1313722   SI1440672   SI1440776  SI1441313
```

How do I do  that in MS Access?

Comment: From a database design standpoint, I would suggest that you drop the `TIMES_REPEATED` column and then leave the rest alone. Having multiple (and an indeterminate number of) columns with the same/interchangeable meaning would turn into a huge pain later on.

Comment: why do you have `mysql` tagged if this is an access question

Comment: My bad! I took it from automatic suggestions. Changed it.